Formula Field - Apex code issue
I have two custom objects, PG and Funding Source. Within the PG object, there is a field called Date_of_Birth__c, which is a formula field that pulls the DOB from the contact. This field shows up fine in the PG object record, however, when I reference this field with apex code in the custom object Funding Source, it remains blank. All other fields pull through, but for some reason this field will not. I'm viewing as the administrator, so I'm thinking it's not a security level thing. I've also set the class as "without sharing" to bypass for other users. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.
<aura:iteration items="{!v.PGs}" var="PGs">
    <tr scope="row">
      <td> <a target="_blank" href="{!v.url +'/'+ PGs.Id}">{!PGs.Name}</a></td>
      <td> {!PGs.Ownership__c}%</td>
      <td> {!PGs.FirstName__c}&nbsp;{!PGs.LastName__c}</td>
      <td> {!PGs.TitlePG__c}</td>
      <td> {!PGs.Title_FP__c}</td>
      <td> {!PGs.Ssn__c}</td>
      <td> {!PGs.Address__c},&nbsp;{!PGs.City__c}&nbsp;{!PGs.State__c},&nbsp;{!PGs.Zip__c}</td>
      <td> {!PGs.Phone__c}</td>
      <td> {!PGs.Date_Of_Birth__c}</td>
    </tr>
  </aura:iteration>


Do I understand correctly and you have the same formula field on the "Funding Source" object? Check your field level access. Even you as System Admin can well have no access (but you can correct that). If you can access Contact information from PG, sharing will be of no importance here.

@FelixvanHove field level access for Date_of_Birth__c (within PG object)  is set to read only for all profiles. DOB (which Date_of_Birth__c references in formula) is editable within Contact object for all profiles. The funding source object does not have a formula field. I created a "snapshot" of the related PG's to the funding source to pull this information into the Funding Source object for quick-view.

when I reference this field with apex code in the custom object Funding Source, it remains blank - please use [edit] to show the schema between Funding Source and PG and the Apex code used to reference Date_Of_Birth__c.

It appears the field name is Date_of_Birth__c (note: lowercase o), but you referenced it as {!PGs.Date_Of_Birth__c} (note: capital O). JavaScript is cAsE-sEnSiTiVe, but Apex isn't. When using Aura or Lightning Web Components, always verify the casing of the field name as it appears in the Setup screen or as described in an object/field describe result.

this was it! Thank you, great eye
